# How to color custom column exactly like a header in JavaFX?

Tags: java, css, javafx, tableview, javafx-8

I would like to simulate database table GUI with JavaFX TableView, which has special column to denote row status. Here is the example from MS Access:

[image]

Hence, I would like to have special column with exact same colors, as the table header. I don't want to guess style explicitly, I wan't it to inherit colors which are already set for a header.

Is it possible?

Comment: The page is not HTML or even DOM I guess. They have their own hierarchy in memory, not visible in browser.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Because your tags included [css], I presumed this was a web application. My bad.

Comment: But JavaFX is really using CSS :) This appears to be ambiguous term itself :)

Answer (score 0):

The default stylesheet uses

```
-fx-background-color: -fx-box-border, -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color;
-fx-background-insets: 0, 0 1 1 0, 1 2 2 1;
```

for the headers. So you could try something like:

```
.row-header-cell {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-box-border, -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 1 1 0, 1 2 2 1;
}

.table-row-cell:selected .row-header-cell {
    -fx-body-color: gold ;
}
```

and then use a cell factory on the "row header" column:

```
TableColumn<...> rowHeaderColumn = ... ;
rowHeaderColumn.setCellFactory(col -> {
    TableCell<...> cell = new TableCell<>();
    cell.getStyleClass().add("row-header-cell");
    return cell ;
});
```